# Programmatically move a toolbar on top of the iPhone keyboard

Tags: iphone, ios4

How do I get the tool bar moving with the keyboard? (when it pops up) 
And down again? (when it resigns as first responder)

I've tried doing some research, but a lot has changed in 4.0

Answer (score 0):

Turns out you can do this
put a UITextView in the toolbar, (you can even hide it)

```
textView.inputAccessoryView = myToolBar;
```

in an init method, and you're done.

Dont forget to make sure your toolbar comes back!